# libphy: PHY 4a101000.mdio:01 not found in Beagleboneblack

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, beagleboneblack

I am connecting a LCD cap to the beagleboneblack,it was working fine but suddenly I start to have this message

```
[34.197758] libphy: PHY 4a101000.mdio:01 not found                           
[34.203275] net eth0: phy 4a101000.mdio:01 not found on slave 1
```

and it is not logging in to the desktop, How can I fix that